# .htaccess & httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to get the directories in my /var/www/html/ directory to not show the "index of..." and all files residing in it. Do I need to edit httpd.conf and put .htaccess files in each directory to ensure the contents are hidden? I have Apache version 2.2.3 on CentOS 5.

Is this the part of httpd.conf I need to edit?

```
<Directory "/var/www/error">
    AllowOverride None
    Options IncludesNoExec
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AddHandler type-map var
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    LanguagePriority en es de fr
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>
```

Do I put a .htaccess file with this in each directory?

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can edit the main config file then add `-Indexes` to your Options line

```
Options IncludesNoExec -Indexes
```

and restart your apache service.

It's doing this because there is no [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) file. You could just put a blank index.html file in your directory. You could add the -Indexes to a .htaccess too.

Comment: Thanks for the response I changed the Options in <Directory "/var/www/error">
 only. I restarted httpd and it didn't work. Is there another part of the conf file I need to change?

Comment: I also made an .htaccess file in a directory with Options IncludesNoExec -Indexes and restart apache. No luck there either.

Comment: Yes, you need to find the <Directory /var/www/html> configuration block.

Comment: <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory> 

Should I make "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks" "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -Indexes" or "Options IncludesNoExec -Indexes"

Comment: The latter should do it.

Comment: Just change Indexes to -Indexes

Comment: And that it did. Thank you for your help. You've bettered my understanding of how this giant .conf file for apache works. Have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

in your http.conf just add the -Indexes to your options.

IE

```
<Directory "/var/www/error">
    AllowOverride None
    Options IncludesNoExec -Indexes
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AddHandler type-map var
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    LanguagePriority en es de fr
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but it makes sense to just disable the corresponding module:

```
# a2dismod autoindex
```